# typedef and operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I typedef an integer or integer array or any known type:

```
typedef int int2
```

Then I overload operator * for int2 pairs, now if I initialize variables a and b as int. Then will my * between a and b be the overloaded * ?

How do I achieve overloading an int and yet also use * for int the way they are. Should I create a new type?

Comment: Perhaps use an enumeration rather than an int?  You can define custom operators for enumerations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a **Strong Typedef**.

Boost offered version that should work for you, or at least help you resolve your need :

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are talking about C++:
Operator overloads have to take at least one argument of user-defined type. The `typedef` doesn't change anything, as it does not introduce a new type and only provides a synonym.

Answer (score 4):

C does not allow operator overloading.

Comment: Though it was not originally 100% clear that this was a C++ question, the question has now been updated to clarify. So while originally this probably should have just been a comment, now it's definitely not a relevant answer. Please remove it.